# Print contents of HttpParams / HttpUriRequest?

Tags: java, httpclient

I have an [HttpUriRequest](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest.html) instance, is there a way to print all the parameters it contains? For example, I can almost get them like:

```
HttpUriRequest req = ...;
HttpParams params = req.getParams();
for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); i++) { // ?
    println(params.getParam(i); // ?
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: in what package is your HttpUriRequest?

Comment: import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;

Answer (score 5):

You can simply iterate over all Header fields.

```
HttpUriRequest req = ...;
.......
Header[] headerFields = request.getAllHeaders();
for(int e = 0; e<header.length; e++){                                    
    System.out.println(headerFields[e].getName() + ": " + headerFields[e].getValue());
}
```

The suggested method params.toString() does not work.

Comment: I believe the user is asking for params not headers.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for the HTTP parameters or the URI parameters?

The HTTP parameters are things like user-agent, socket buffer size, protocol version, etc.

The URI parameters are the client values that get passed as part of the request, e.g.

```
?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

If you're looking for the URI parameters, try something like this:

```
List<String> uriParams = Arrays.asList(request.getURI().getQuery().split("&"));
```

But if you do want the raw HTTP params, it's a little more complicated because not all implementations of HttpParams supports `getNames()`. You'd have to do something like this:

```
HttpParamsNames params = (HttpParamsNames)request.getParams();
Set<String> names;

if (params instanceof ClientParamsStack) {
    names = new HashSet<>();

    // Sorted by priority, see ClientParamsStack
    ClientParamsStack cps = (ClientParamsStack)params;
    if (cps.getApplicationParams() != null) {
        names.addAll(((HttpParamsNames)cps.getApplicationParams()).getNames());
    }
    if (cps.getClientParams() != null) {
        names.addAll(((HttpParamsNames)cps.getClientParams()).getNames());
    }
    if (cps.getRequestParams() != null) {
        names.addAll(((HttpParamsNames)cps.getRequestParams()).getNames());
    }
    if (cps.getOverrideParams() != null) {
        names.addAll(((HttpParamsNames)cps.getOverrideParams()).getNames());
    }
} else {
    names = params.getNames();
}

for (String name : names) {
    System.out.println(name + ": " + request.getParams().getParameter(name));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpUriRequest extends HttpMessage, which has getAllHeaders(), getParams() etc.

Take a look here: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/index.html, search for HttpMessage

Answer (score 0):

You could create a work around by casting it to BasicHttpParams object.

`BasicHttpParams basicParams = (BasicHttpParams) params;`

This give you access to `getNames()` which contains a `HashSet<String>` of the parameters

You can then iterate through it printing out the parameter name alongside it's value.

See 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57600124/5622596
for possible solution