# Access all entries of HttpParams

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

Is there a way of iterating over all entries of an `HttpParams` object?

Someone else had a similar problem ( [Print contents of HttpParams / HttpUriRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145521) ) but the answers don't really work.

When looking into [BasicHttpParams](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1.4/org/apache/http/params/BasicHttpParams.java) I see that there is a `HashMap` inside, but no way of accessing it directly. Also `AbstractHttpParams`
 doesn't provide any direct access to all entries.

Since I cannot rely on predefined key names the ideal way would be to iterate just over all entries `HttpParams` encapsulates. Or at least get a list of key names. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HttpParams is used to create HttpEntity set on HttpEntityEnclosedRequestBase object and you can then have a List back using the following code

```
final HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://...");

final ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("a_param", username));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("a_second_param", password));

//  add the parameters to the httpPost
HttpEntity entity;
try
{
    entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params);
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
}
catch (final UnsupportedEncodingException e)
{
    // this should never happen.
    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
}
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpPost.getEntity();

try
{
    List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>( URLEncodedUtils.parse(httpEntity) );
}
catch (IOException e)
{
}
```

Comment: I did a similar thing just to get the parameters off of a URI (this is a Groovy snippet, the same holds in Java):

`def uri = new URI("https://www.yahoo.com?foo=bar")
List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(URLEncodedUtils.parse(uri, "UTF-8"));
parameters.each { parameter -> println parameter.name + ": " + parameter.value }`

This is a decent way to deconstruct the parameters for a request without messing around with the HttpParams object, which is mostly useless unless you know exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you know there's a `HashMap` inside, and you really need to get those params, you can always force your way in using reflection.

```
Class clazz = httpParams.getClass();

Field fields[] = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
System.out.println("Access all the fields");
for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){ 
   System.out.println("Field Name: " + fields[i].getName()); 
   fields[i].setAccessible(true); 
   System.out.println(fields[i].get(httpParams) + "\n"); 
}
```

Comment: I somehow assumed that there must be some other way, other than using reflection. Isn't an `HttpParams` object processed somewhere in `HttpClient`, where it would need to be stripped in order to prepare the HTTP request?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to finish building your solution to view all HttpParams via a cast to BasicHttpParams

```
HttpParams params = //Construction of params not shown

BasicHttpParams basicParams = (BasicHttpParams) params;
Set<String> keys = basicParams.getNames();

for (String key : keys) {
    System.out.println("[Key]:" + key + " [Value]:" + basicParams.getParameter(key));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I just use this to set the Params:

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
get.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
get.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout",20000);
```

Comment: But I wanted to read all parameters from an `HttpRequest`. So sticking with your example, get a list from `get.getParams()`.