# Java httpPost not posting data correctly (Apache library)?

Tags: java, apache, entity, http-post

Quick question as I've tried many debugging options and none have helped identify the problem. I'm using Java and the Apache HttpPost library.

I have httpGet and httpHead working fine currently, however I can't get httpPost to send the variables correctly. I set up a debug PHP script on my server to simply dump the contents of `$_POST`. Works correct if I do a curl request in terminal.

Code snippet:

```
    // create new HttpPost object
    postRequest = new HttpPost(url);

    // add post variables
    postRequest.setEntity(new StringEntity(body, ContentType.TEXT_HTML));

    // execute request
    response = executeRequest(postRequest);
```

The String variable "body" is just a string, currently containing "test=testing". The output from this PHP debug script:

```
<?php 

  echo "Input Stream: ";

  var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));

  echo "POST Variables: ";

  var_dump($_POST);

?>
```

is :

```
Input Stream: string(12) "test=testing"
POST Variables: array(0) {
}
```

Does anyone know why it's not getting picked up and dumped in the `$_POST` variable? Highly irritating as I've spent hours on this!

Any help would be appreciated :) thanks

Comment: When you say "Apache HttpPost" library, do you mean [the HttpComponents HttpClient library](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html)?

Comment: @david yes, I'm using those libraries

Comment: What does your executeRequest method do?

Comment: @Alex performs the HttpClient execute method and returns a httpResponse object, which is subsequently checked to see if valid response (200) and then response entity printed out

Answer (score 0):

See [Access all entries of HttpParams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379768/access-all-entries-of-httpparams?lq=1)

To build the URI including the parameters, use:

```
NameValuePair nvp = new BasicNameValuePair("test", "testing");
String query = URLEncodedUtils.format(nvp, "utf-8"); // use your favourite charset here
URI uri = new URI("http://localhost/app?" + query;
HttpPost postReq = new HttpPost(uri);
httpClient.execute(postReq);
```

This will result in: `http://localhost/app?test=testing` being requested.