# Is there a Groovy way to print request HttpClient sends

Tags: groovy, apache-httpclient-4.x

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145521/print-contents-of-httpparams-httpurirequest), but that is not very Groovy!  I am just wondering if there is a simple way in the HttpClient request closure to print out the request being sent?  This information is somewhat available in the code, but it would really help development if I could get this entered into the log files.

Comment: If the answer provided works for you then you can respond to the answer provider by accepting the answer at the least. This would encourage community members to respond to your questions (which I think you might have) in future.

Comment: If it is okay with you, (and actually even if it isn't) I was waiting to see if there were any other answers that might be superior for one business day.

Comment: Agree. My point was about a simple response like "That works, I would wait if I can get any other response before accepting". It happened many times here in the community that answer provider does a good amount of  work/research to provide a splendid answer but OP did not bother to respond/provide feedback to the answer provider (forget about accepting). No offense intended in your case. :)

Comment: Ok, that's a good idea which I have not done before.  In the future, I will do that whenever I want to wait a bit to see if additional answers come.

Comment: Much appreciated the understanding. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code can be converted to this groovy:

```
request.allHeaders.each {
    println "${it.name} : ${it.value}"
}
```